# Function overloaded ambiguity in inheritance wherein functions have same number of parameters

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class base1{
public :
   void greet(int a){
   cout<<"How are you ?"<<a<<endl;
   }

};
class base2{
public:
   void greet(int a){
   cout<<"Comment ca va ?"<<a<<endl;
   }


};
class derived : public base1 ,public base2{
public:
   void greet(int){
       base1::greet(int);  // gives error here ...
   }
};

int main(){
derived d;
d.greet(9);   // without defining greet() in we get error
return 0;
}
```

Gives me error :
Line 22 : expected primary-expression before 'int'
Please help. I google this problem but everywhere it was with no arguments ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base1::greet(int)` isn't a call to the `base1::greet` function. For it to be a call you need to pass an actual value (like e.g. `base1::greet(9)`).

However it's a little hard to pass a value to `base1::greet` since the argument to `derived::greet` is ignored. You need to accept the argument and pass it on:

```
void greet(int value)
{
    // Call base1::greet with the value passed to this function (derived::greet)
    base1::greet(value);
}
```

---

Besides the above, if you want `derived::greet` to *always* call `base1::greet` you can pull in the `base1::greet` function into the scope of `derived`with the `using` keyword:

```
class derived : public base1, public base2
{
public:
    // All calls to derived::greet will actually be base1::greet
    using base1::greet;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and time...It helped me